# Finding the smith number between given range

Tags: java

I will get to the point quickly. Basically smith numbers are: Composite number the sum of whose digits is the sum of the digits of its prime factors (excluding 1). (The primes are excluded since they trivially satisfy this condition). One example of a Smith number is the beast number 666=2·3·3·37, since 6+6+6=2+3+3+(3+7)=18.

what i've tried:

1. In a for loop first i get the sum of the current number's(i) digits
2. In same loop i try to get the sum of the number's prime factors digits.
3. I've made another method to check if current number that is going to proccessed in for loop is prime or not,if its prime it will be excluded

But my code is seems to not working can you guys help out?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        smithInrange(1, 50);
    }

    public static void smithInrange(int start_val, int end_val) {

        for (int i = start_val; i < end_val; i++) {
            if(!isPrime(i)) { //since we banned prime numbers from this process i don't include them 
            int for_digit_sum = i, digit = 0, digit_sum = 0, for_factor_purpose = i, smith_sum = 0;
            int first = 0, second = 0, last = 0;
            // System.out.println("current number is" + i);
            while (for_digit_sum > 0) { // in this while loop i get the sum of current number's digits

                digit = for_digit_sum % 10;
                digit_sum += digit;
                for_digit_sum /= 10;
            }
            // System.out.println("digit sum is"+digit_sum);

            while (for_factor_purpose % 2 == 0) { // i divide the current number to 2 until it became an odd number
                first += 2;
                for_factor_purpose /= 2;
            }
            // System.out.println("the first sum is " + first);
            for (int j = 3; j < Math.sqrt(for_factor_purpose); j += 2) {
                while (for_factor_purpose % j == 0) { // this while loop is for getting the digit sum of every prime
                                                        // factor that j has
                    int inner_digit = 0, inner_temp = j, inner_digit_sum = 0;
                    while (inner_temp > 0) {
                        inner_digit = inner_temp % 10;
                        second += inner_digit;
                        inner_temp /= 10;
                    }
                    // System.out.println("the second sum is " + second);
                    for_factor_purpose /= j;
                }
            }
            int last_temp = for_factor_purpose, last_digit = 0, last_digit_sum = 0;
            if (for_factor_purpose > 2) {
                while (last_temp > 0) {
                    last_digit = last_temp % 10;
                    last += last_digit;
                    last_temp /= 10;
                }
                // System.out.println("last is " + last);

            }
            smith_sum = first + second + last;
            // System.out.println("smith num is "+ smith_sum);
            // System.out.println(smith_sum);
            if (smith_sum == digit_sum) {
                System.out.println("the num founded is" + i);
            }
        }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(i) + 1;
        for (int k = 2; k < sqrt; k++) {
            if (i % k == 0) {
                // number is perfectly divisible - no prime
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

the output is:
the num founded is4
the num founded is9
the num founded is22
the num founded is25
the num founded is27
the num founded is49

how ever the smith number between this range(1 and 50) are:
4, 22 and 27

edit:I_ve found the problem which is :
Math.sqrt(for_factor_purpose) it seems i should add 1 to it to eliminate square numbers. Thanks to you guys i've see sthe solution on other perspectives.
Keep coding!

Comment: Use a debugger and try to find `smithInrange(25, 26);` (since you already know that 25 is incorrectly identified as smith number.) If you do that you will find that your algorithm for finding the prime factors of 25 is wrong (it terminates to early)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main loop for printing Smith numbers.

```
      for (int i = 3; i < 10000; i++) {
         if (isSmith(i)) {
            System.out.println(i + " is a Smith number.");
         }
      }
```

The test method to determine if the supplied number is a Smith number.  The list of primes is only increased if the last prime is smaller in magnitude than the number under test.

```java
   static boolean isSmith(int v) {
      int sum = 0;
      int save = v;

      int lastPrime = primes.get(primes.size() - 1);
      if (lastPrime < v) {
         genPrimes(v);
      }
      outer:
      for (int p : primes) {
         while (save > 1) {
            if (save % p != 0) {
               continue outer;
            }
            sum += sumOfDigits(p);
            save /= p;
         }
         break;
      }
      return sum == sumOfDigits(v) && !primes.contains(v);
   }
```

Helper method to sum the digits of a number.

```
   static int sumOfDigits(int i) {
      return String.valueOf(i).chars().map(c -> c - '0').sum();
   }
```

And the prime generator.  It uses the list as it is created to determine if a given
number is a prime.

```
   static List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 3));
   static void genPrimes(int max) {
      int next = primes.get(primes.size() - 1);
      outer:
      while (next <= max) {
         next += 2;
         for (int p : primes) {
            if (next % p == 0) {
               continue outer;
            }
            if (p * p > next) {
               break;
            }
         }
         primes.add(next);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not want to spoil the answer finding, but just some simpler code snippets,
making everything simpler, and more readable.

```
public boolean isSmith(int a) {
    if (a < 2) return false;
    int factor = findDivisor(a);
    if (factor == a) return false;

    int sum = digitSum(a);
    // loop:
        a /= factor;
        sum -= digitSum(factor);
    ...
}

boolean isPrime(int a){
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= a; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int findDivisor(int a){
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= a; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int digitSum(int a) {
   if (a < 10) {
       return a;
   }
   int digit = a % 10;
   int rest = a / 10;
   return digit + digitSum(rest); 
}
```

As you see integer division 23 / 10 == 2, and modulo (remainder) `%`: 23 % 10 == 3 can simplify things.

Instead of isPrime, finding factor(s) is more logical. In fact the best solution is *not* using findDivisor, but immediately find all factors

```
    int factorsSum = 0;
    int factorsCount = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= a; i++) {
        while (a % i == 0) {
            factorsSum += digitSum(i);
            a /= i;
            factorsCount++;
        }
    }

    // The remaining factor >= sqrt(original a) must be a prime.
    // (It cannot contain smaller factors.)
    factorsSum += digitSum(a);
    factorsCount++;
```

Comment: Thank you for contribution and your advice:) I've just started coding ,i think by time passes i will get better.

Comment: I believe your findFactors method is incorrect. Since it only goes up to the square root of a you are missing factors that are larger than that. For example. 202 has two prime factors, 2 and 101. But the square root of 202 is < 15.

Comment: @WJS _Good point._ I was aware that the last loop indeed ends with a value for `a` being the last, prime factor AFAIK. I have added the code to the answer. Originally I did not want to spell everything out, and leave enough requiring mental gymnastics. About the limit: intuitively it seemed better to let the loop not go till i <= a, but for such a logarithmic splitting, I might be wrong. _My main motivation for an answer where the avoidance of things like double division and sqrt. Upto a dynamic adaption of `i*i <= a`_

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. If you need further help, please let me know. The code is pretty self explanatory and a decent bit was taken from your code but if you need me to explain it let me know.

In short, I created methods to check if a number is a smith number and then checked each int in the range.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println(smithInRange)
    }
    public int factor;
    public boolean smithInRange(int a, int b){
        for (int i=Math.min(a,b);i<=Math.max(a,b);i++) if(isSmith(i)) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isSmith(int a){
        if(a<2) return false;
        if(isPrime(a)) return false;
        int digits=0;
        int factors=0;
        String x=a+¨" ";
        for(int i=0;i<x.length()-1;i++) digits+= Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i,i+1));
        ArrayList<Integer> pF = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        pF.add(a);
        while(!aIsPrime(pF)){
            int num = pF.get(pF.size-1)
            pF.remove(pF.size()-1);
            pF.add(factor);
            pF.add(num/factor)
        }
        for(int i: pF){
            if((factors+"").length()==1)factors+= i;
            else{
                String ss= i+" ";
                int nums=0;
                for(int j=0;j<ss.length()-1;j++){
                    nums+=Integer.parseInt(ss.substring(j,j+1));
                }
            }
        }
        return (factors==digits);
    }
    public boolean isPrime(int a){
        for(int i=2;i<=(int)Math.sqrt(a),i++){
            String s = (double)a/(double)i+"";
            if(s.substring(s.length()-2).equals(".0")){
                return false;
                factor = i;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean aIsPrime(ArrayList<int> a){
        for(int i: a) if (!isPrime(a)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```